# Change the mapping of F5 on the basis of specific file type

Tags: vim, keymapping

The current mapping of my <kbd>F5</kbd> key is:

```
imap <F5> <esc>:w\|!python %<CR>
```

Now I want that if I'm editing any python file *(it will be better if it also recognizes file other than standard `.py` format like `.pyd` etc)* then this mapping works as it is. But, if I edit a Java file it is mapped to something like:

```
imap <F5> <esc>:w\|!javac %<CR>
```

And when I'm editing any `.c` or `.cpp` file then <kbd>F5</kbd> is mapped to this:

```
imap <F5> <esc>:w\|!make %<CR>
```

I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Take a look at [SingleCompile](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3115) plugin. I'm not 100% sure whether it can be configured to run `make` for `.c` or `.cpp` files, but it should be possible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are problems with both given answer and original mapping. First of all, for buffer-local mappings there is `*map <buffer>`. Second, with `<buffer>` you don’t need to use `BufEnter` events and can instead use `Filetype` which are launched only once. Third, you have one error (2.), one potential problem (1.) and one place that can be optimized in original mappings:

1. you should not be using `imap`, it makes it very easy to accidentally break old mappings when adding new ones
2. `!python %` will break once file contain a special symbol (space, semicolon, quot, dollar, …)
3. using `:update` instead of `:write` avoids useless writes in some cases

My variant:

```
autocmd Filetype c,cpp  inoremap <buffer> <F5> <C-o>:update<Bar>execute '!make '.shellescape(expand('%:r'), 1)<CR>
autocmd Filetype python inoremap <buffer> <F5> <C-o>:update<Bar>execute '!python '.shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>
autocmd Filetype java   inoremap <buffer> <F5> <C-o>:update<Bar>execute '!javac '.shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>
```

Comment: Great answer! And to prevent scattering of various autocmds in your .vimrc (it's fine in the beginning, but slowly turns into an uncomprehensible mess), I prefer putting those `:inoremap`s into `~/.vim/ftplugin/<filetype>_mappings.vim`, which is sourced automatically by Vim, and gives you modularization.

Comment: @ZyX Can you modify these mappings to also work in **normal** mode?

Comment: @Santosh You can make them work in normal mode by replacing “i” with “n” in “inoremap” and removing “<C-o>”. But you have to completely copy this block.

Comment: @Santosh By the way, previous version contained a bug: I’ve written mappings that will work in *normal* mode, but they were *insert* mode mappings. Fixed by prepending “<C-o>”.

Comment: @ZyX Hey!! I said "**also work in normal mode**". I want the same mapping to work in normal as well as insert mode. Do I have to add another three lines of mappings?

Comment: @Santosh There is no way to use one command to define one mapping for those two modes. There are commands for visual+select, visual+normal+operator-pending and command+insert abbreviations, but nothing for insert+normal. You have to define two separate mappings.

Comment: @ZyX What is difference between `imap` and `inoremap`?

Comment: @Santosh Try launching these mappings after doing `noremap : ;` and `noremap ; :`. `imap` version will break, `inoremap` won’t. This example I refer to as “classical” because 1. these two mappings break tons of others and 2. swapping meanings of these keys makes sense because semicolon is easier to type (no shift) and colon is used much more often then semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
au BufEnter *.py map <F5> <esc>:w\|!python %<CR>
au BufEnter *.java imap <F5> <esc>:w\|!javac %<CR>
au BufEnter *.c, *.cpp imap <F5> <esc>:w\|!make %<CR>
```

I'm not 100% sure about the comma separated file types, trying to verify...

The vim docs are usually pretty nasty to try to figure out how to use commands, but these should help get you started:

```
:h BufEnter
:h :autocmd
```

Note: You may have to restart vim for these changes to overwrite the current autocommand groups.

Comment: You can comment separate, but not with a space after the comma. Also, you can do `*.py*` do include `.pyd` files, etc.

Comment: OK, I have a problem. C programs need to be compiled form command line   like this: `make program`, but this mapping stimulates this: `make program.c`. Any way to remove that trailing `.c` extension? And give command line only the filename, not extension?

Comment: @Conner You answered the another question. In that way I can do `*.c*` for both C and C++ files, 'cause both's command are `make`. But still the extension is the problem.

Comment: @Santosh you can use `%:r` instead of `%` to leave off the file extension.

Comment: @Santosh See `:help %:r` and `:help :r`. They are different.

Comment: @andy-ray why do you use `BufEnter` event? I think `FileType` is better for such things.