# nerdtree is breaking one of my mappings

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I use the following mapping to run the python interpreter when I press F5:

```
autocmd Filetype python nnoremap <buffer> <F5> <C-o>:update<Bar>execute '!python '.shellescape(@%, 1)<CR>
```

Occasionally though the current file variable is expanded to something like "NERD_tree_1..." which of course causes this error:

```
powershell -command "python NERD_tree_1p"
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'NERD_tree_1p': [Errno 2] No such file o
r directory
shell returned 1
Hit any key to close this window...
```

Not sure how nerd tree is causing this problem or how to fix it.

Comment: Are you executing this in a NerdTree buffer? Was this buffer at one time a NerdTree buffer?

Comment: Not sure, what would cause it to execute in a nerdtree buffer. Seems to happen almost randomly. The first few times I hit F5 it runs fine then it will give me that error. I also notice that when I get that error, when I close out of the command prompt and return to vim I have an empty buffer open called "NERD_tree_1" which I have to close.

Comment: `@%` expands to the current file. It should not be `NERD...` unless you executing this command in the NerdTree buffer that was at one time a python file as you have not specified a `b:undo_ftplugin` to tear down the mapping upon a filetype change.

Comment: How would I do that? Add b:undo_ftplugin to the autocmd I'm using for the mapping?

Comment: You can certainly try. However I doubt that is the root of your problem, b/c it would be very odd for NerdTree or any plugin to alter the previous buffer to display its own contents. If I were you I would make sure you focus on the times it fails and double check where your cursor was before you hit `<f5>`. If the problem persist after you verify your cursor position, I would suggest you open an issue w/ NerdTree. An alternate solution would be to simply not use NerdTree there is little to gain in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The register `%` contains the current buffer name. Somehow, you seem to be in the scratch buffer that NERDTree uses to display its directory tree when the error occurs.

You should have noticed that the cursor is in the "wrong" (i.e. non-Python) buffer. If this happens in a Python buffer, I cannot explain that.

You can make your mapping more robust to include a check for Python filetype, like this:

```
... if &filetype ==# 'python'<Bar>update<Bar>execute '!python '.shellescape(@%, 1)<Bar>endif<CR>
```

Comment: I thought this mapping already did that. I got it from this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030965/change-the-mapping-of-f5-on-the-basis-of-specific-file-type

Comment: Right, but you have some strange interactions (see the comment from Peter Rincker). As there's too few information, all I can offer is a workaround to make this more robust.